# Liferay 6.1 TextEditor Line Break Issue

Tags: ckeditor, liferay, line-breaks

I'm having issue with the Liferay6.1 TextEditor/CKEditor line breaks. It adds too much space between paragraphs. Is there any way I can change the config so that the line breaks add less space between paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

By rendering of articles you can replace the output stream of articles over the portal properties:

```
journal.transformer.regex.pattern.0=
journal.transformer.regex.replacement.0=
```

search regex what you need and put this to `portal-ext.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it all a matter of the css you have in your theme? You can change the line height, margins etc. in your theme to reflect the dimensions you need.

For a start, try to manipulate the css with Firebug (or whatever is the equivalent for your browser) to change the line height, then bring the changes forward to your theme